# TypeORM Custom naming strategy doesn't work correctly

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, orm, typeorm

I am using TypeORM 0.2.29.I use postgres as the database. I added a custom naming strategy to get readable names for constraints. But turns out it doesn't work as intended. Any clue will be appreciated. Thank you

Here is my naming strategy:

```
import { DefaultNamingStrategy, Table, NamingStrategyInterface } from "typeorm";

export class CustomNamingStrategy extends DefaultNamingStrategy implements NamingStrategyInterface {

    private joinColumns(columnNames: string[]): string {
        return columnNames.join('_');
    }
    private getTableName(tableOrName: Table | string): string {
        tableOrName =
            typeof tableOrName === "string" ? tableOrName : tableOrName.name;
        return tableOrName;
    } 

    foreignKeyName(tableOrName: Table | string, columnNames: string[], _referencedTablePath?: string, _referencedColumnNames?: string[]): string {
        console.log(`${this.getTableName(tableOrName)}_${this.joinColumns(columnNames)}_fkey`)
        return `${this.getTableName(tableOrName)}_${this.joinColumns(columnNames)}_fkey`
    }

    primaryKeyName(tableOrName: Table | string,  columnNames: string[]): string {
        console.log({columnNames})
        console.log(`${this.getTableName(tableOrName)}_pkey`)
        return `${this.getTableName(tableOrName)}_pkey`
    }

    uniqueConstraintName(tableOrName: Table | string, columnNames: string[]): string {
        console.log(`${this.getTableName(tableOrName)}_ukey`)
        return `${this.getTableName(tableOrName)}_${this.joinColumns(columnNames)}_ukey`;
    }

    indexName(tableOrName: Table | string, columnNames: string[]): string {
        console.log(`${this.getTableName(tableOrName)}_${this.joinColumns(columnNames)}_idx`)
        return `${this.getTableName(tableOrName)}_${this.joinColumns(columnNames)}_idx`;
     }
}
```

Any way to fix this naming issue?